# onBackgroundMessage is never called, when building release *.aab

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working with FCM and flutter_local_notification (i get 'data' push-notifications and after that construct my local notification). And everything works fine when building in debug mode and when building *.apk (even in release mode), i receive and able to interact with notifications. But when I'm trying to build *.aab in release mode - as mentioned, onBackgroundMssage never fired.

Also, my compileSDKVersion: 33

What doctor says:
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1466])
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.73.1)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

Tried:

- According to this known issue (https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9534), i added @pragma above the handler - and after that *.apk in release mode started to work fine.